# Desabilitar boton HTML en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Quiero hacer una función en el propio código HTML que cada vez que pulsemos un botón un contador sume hasta seis y cuando llegue al limite (6). Quede el botón desabilitado. ¿ Alguna ayuda ?

Este es el boton:

```html
<button type="button" onclick="random()">Lanzar dado !!!</button>
```

Comment: Publica la función que se ejecuta cuando presionas el botón, para ver como lo tienes

Comment: function random() {

    do {
        var r = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
        var randomRepetido = comprobacionRandom(r);



    }while(randomRepetido == true);
    preguntadas.push(r);
    asignacionPreguntas(r);
}

Comment: anida varias funciones

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pues realmente lo que debes hacer con tu contador y el botón es lo siguiente:

```js
var contador = 0;

function random(elemento){
    if(contador >= 5){
        elemento.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
    }else{
        contador++
    }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="random(this)">Lanzar dado !!!</button>
```

Espero que te sirva, saludos !

Comment: no me funciona sobrecargando la funcion con this en el html. donde creo el boton. Ahora pulso y no se ejecuta nada. Puedo referenciarlo por el id que le de al botton? Y hacer algo similar a id.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');

Comment: Y estas mandando `this` como parámetro de la función `onclick="random(this)"`

Comment: Sii estoy pasándole el parámetro.

Comment: Es extraño que no te de, debe haber algo en el resto de código de tu función que esta generando conflicto, de todas formas puedes seleccionar el elemento por su id y asignarle el `attr` `document.getElementById('#elemento').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');`

Comment: Gracis lo probaré

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo así:

```js
function button(){
var x=document.getElementById("btn");
var y=document.getElementById("p");
setTimeout(function(){ y.innerHTML="1" }, 1000);
setTimeout(function(){ y.innerHTML="2" }, 2000);
setTimeout(function(){ y.innerHTML="3" }, 3000);
setTimeout(function(){ y.innerHTML="4" }, 4000);
setTimeout(function(){ y.innerHTML="5" }, 5000);
setTimeout(function(){y.innerHTML="6";  x.disabled=true }, 6000);}
```

```html
<button id="btn" onclick="button()">Lanzar dado</button>
<p id="p">0</p>
```